# how to import graphs from excel to datawindow in powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I want to import graph from excel to data window and want to change values at run time.Is this possible.If YES then how to do it.I have searched a lot but found no support.

Comment: Hmmm, change the values where... in Excel? in the datawindow?  also when you say 'import graph' you mean the data or the visual representation?

Comment: Only the visual template and setting the values from DW or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

From the datawindow, go to Insert > Control > OLE .. [image: insert control->OLE...]

[image: Insert Object]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PowerBuilder datawindow control function "ImportFile" to import data but there is no direct support for Excel. You could easily save your excel data as CSV, Tab Delimited, etc. then import it.

You can save data in a datawindow in many more file formats than you can import data. The following are supported using SaveAs.

PowerBuilder Syntax

```
integer dwcontrol.SaveAs ( { string filename, saveastype saveastype, boolean colheading { , encoding encoding } } )
```

When using ImportFile function, you specify the file format type using an enumerated value.

An enumerated value of the SaveAsType DataWindow constant or a number representing that value (see SaveAsType). If this argument is specified, the filename argument can be specified without an extension. Valid type arguments for ImportFile are:

- Text!
- CSV!
- XML!
- DBase2!
- DBase3!

**PowerBuilder - Syntax**

```
long dwcontrol.ImportFile ( {saveastype importtype}, string filename {, long startrow {, long endrow {, long startcolumn {, long endcolumn {, long dwstartcolumn } } } } } )
```

**Example code for importing data into datawindow**

```
dw_control.ImportFile(XML!, myxmldata)
```

**Return codes for ImportFile function**

Events

ImportFile may trigger an ItemError event.

Returns

Long. Returns the number of rows that were imported if it succeeds and one of the following negative integers if an error occurs:

-1 No rows or startrow value supplied is greater than the number of rows in the file

-2 Empty file

-3 Invalid argument

-4 Invalid input

-5 Could not open the file

-6 Could not close the file

-7 Error reading the text

-8 Unsupported file name suffix (must be *.txt, *.csv, *.dbf or *.xml)

-10 Unsupported dBase file format (not version 2 or 3)

-11 XML Parsing Error; XML parser libraries not found or XML not well formed

-12 XML Template does not exist or does not match the DataWindow

-13 Unsupported DataWindow style for import

-14 Error resolving DataWindow nesting